# How do I properly shut down Log4j, closing all Appenders and, therefore, files

Tags: java, servlets, resources, log4j

My servlet-based web-app sometimes fails to close Log4j log files when redeployed, leaking to file descriptor leakage and occassionally leading to servlet-contained dying from 'too many open files'.

I have a ContextListener, what should I put into its contextDestroyed() to tell log4j to shut down and release all resources?

Quick skim over javadocs revealed Hierachery class with shutdown() method. I have no idea on how to actually get the current Hierachery, and the javadoc states this class has no user-serviceable components inside :)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Try this:

```
org.apache.log4j.LogManager.shutdown();
```

However, the problem you are experiencing is strange and shouldn't be happening. What JVM, container, log4j version are you using?

Comment: I'm using Sun's JVM6, Resin and log4j 1.2.14
I guess it sometimes leaks classloaders and prevents them from recycling (finalizing), I've not figured it out yet.
Thanks for hint!

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem but my solution required two steps:

First, I had to call `LogManager.shutdown()` from a servlets `destroy()` method.

Then I had to fix the `close()` method of our own Appender implementation (which is a subclass of `AppenderSkeleton`), so that it properly closes the appenders from `getAllAppenders()`.

Comment: Servlet destory method can be called anytime (by specification). You should rather use ServletContextListener - there is method contextDestroyed, which is called only once.